# asp.net datareader must be closed

Tags: c#, asp.net, datareader

My code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
//..........
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TempQn WHERE creatorId=  '" +
Session["administratorID"].ToString() + "'";  
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();  
while (dr.Read())
{
    int ids = Int32.Parse(dr["QuestionID"].ToString());
    cmd.CommandText = " INSERT INTO Answers (QuestionId,Answer) Select c.QnId, c.Answer From TempAns c Where c.Id = " + ids + " ";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //this line
}
dr.Close();
```

The error is:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

What kind of command should replace the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`?

Comment: First, building sql query using string concatenation is a bad practice, because it can lead to security flaw. Use SqlParameters instead.

Comment: 2nd, can't you do what you are doing here in a single sql query?

Comment: I guess you open  another datareader in place of .......?

Comment: 3rd: you have to open a new SQL Connection, or load the whole data from the first query in a DataTable (for example), then process each row after.

Comment: Please don't put the solution as the question, it cause confusion - those reading the question need to see the original problem then they can read through the answers and the accepted answer (if exists) is the correct solution. You can add more details but don't overwrite the original question or problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't execute any further SQL statements as long as the DataReader is "active".

To overcome this, store list of the SQL statements then exeucute them after reading:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Question WHERE SurveyID= '" + sID + "'";    
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();  
List<string> arrSQL = new List<string>();
while (dr.Read())
{
    int ids = Int32.Parse(dr["QuestionID"].ToString());
    arrSQL.Add("INSERT INTO Answers (QuestionId,Answer) Select c.QnId, c.Answer From TempAns c Where c.Id = " + ids + " ");
}
dr.Close();

arrSQL.ForEach(strSQL =>
{
    cmd.CommandText = strSQL;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
});
```

Your current code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks though and isn't good practice - you better use Parameter instead of injecting value to the raw SQL - here is how to achieve that:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Question WHERE SurveyID=@id";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", sID);
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();  
List<int> arrQuestions = new List<int>();
while (dr.Read())
{
    int ids = Int32.Parse(dr["QuestionID"].ToString());
    arrQuestions.Add(ids);
}
dr.Close();

cmd.CommandText =  "INSERT INTO Answers (QuestionId, Answer) Select c.QnId, c.Answer From TempAns c Where c.Id = @id";
arrQuestions.ForEach(id =>
{
    cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = id;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
});
```

Comment: Instead of looping with the datareader to populate a List, I would use and SqlTableAdapter to populate a DataTable. It would embrace the ADO.Net classes a bit more

Comment: @SteveB can't see any performance gain here, it's personal taste - DataReader is the most direct way to access the data.

Comment: The idea is not to gain performance, but simply stick with common ado.net classes

Answer (score 1):

You already have one command associated with "cmd".

```
  dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();  
          while (dr.Read())
          {
              int ids = Int32.Parse(dr["QuestionID"].ToString());
              SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Answers (QuestionId,Answer) Select c.QnId, c.Answer From TempAns c Where c.Id = " + ids + " ");
              sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //this line
          }
          dr.Close();
```

So Like ive given above create a new command for the insertion.

Comment: it says : ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Answers (QuestionId,Answer) Select c.QnId, c.Answer From TempAns c Where c.Id = " + ids + " ",con); 
All you have to do is pass the SqlConnection as the second parameter

Answer (score 1):

This single query should do the job (not sure of you exact data model, adapt if required ):

```
INSERT INTO Answers (QuestionId,Answer) 
Select c.QnId, c.Answer 
From TempAns c 
inner join Question q on c.QnId = q.Id
where q.SurveyID = @SurveyID
```

In order to avoid SQl Injection, use this C# code :

```
cmd.CommandTest = @"INSERT INTO Answers (QuestionId,Answer) 
    Select c.QnId, c.Answer 
    From TempAns c 
    inner join Question q on c.QnId = q.Id
    where q.SurveyID = @SurveyID";

SqlParameter param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@SurveyID", SqlDbType.Int);
param.Value = yourSurveyId;

cmd.Open(); // it would be better to check the status before 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Close();
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to change the first select clause. could you please take a look.
because between TempAns and Question table are not related ( no FK)

Comment: there is no need to have a FK for joining table, even if it's often preferable

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a 2nd connection object, you could change your connection string and use MARS ([Multiple active result set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) for this purpose. Add the following statement to your connection string:

```
MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

EDIT:
And like the other's said, use SqlParameters for your parameters and not string concatenation. It's not only a security issue, but also a huge performance hit!

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare a new command object because `cmd` is already being used for reading the data when you are trying to use it for insert statement. Also, don't use string concatenation from sql command, its a bad practice and vulnerable to SQL injection. using parameters.